# Getting Transaction Expiration Error on Mainnet

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, nft, solana-cli, metaboss

I keep getting the following error on mainnet and doing the same transaction again works well.

> Error: Action failed with error: unable to confirm transaction. This
> can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and
> insufficient fee-payer funds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network is likely congested. Raise the priority fee to make it more likely your tx will be processed in a timely fashion.

Some wallets like Phantom automatically add a priority fee as-needed: https://docs.phantom.app/developer-powertools/solana-priority-fees

Comment: I am using Solana-cli wallet and metaboss to update the metadata NFTs, so how is it possible to add/update priority fees in CLI?

Comment: Add a Compute Budget ix into your TX, here you can set an extra fee to pay: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/ComputeBudgetProgram.html